# Remove hex from string php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string like

`0xffffffHello there 0x32ac49human! Nice to 0x334455meet you!`

What would be the best way to remove all the hex substrings? Each hex substring is always 6 characters (color codes)

The output would be `Hello there human! Nice to meet you!`

Comment: What have you tried so far? This can easily be solved using PHP's string functions, or using regular expressions.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I've tried regex but i'm still trying to learn it. You say PHP string function -or- regex. So which php string functions can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a regular expression and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) would be your best option.

For example:

```
echo preg_replace('/0x[0-9a-fA-F]{6}/', '', '0xffffffHello there 0x32ac49human! Nice to 0x334455meet you!');
```

Outputs:

```
Hello there human! Nice to meet you!
```

Regex breakdown pseudocode:

```
/
    0x            #Match '0x'
    [0-9a-fA-F]   #Match any hex character.
    {6}           #Require the hex character match to match 6 times.
/
```

Comment: @user1008134: No, it's not incorrect. I've tested it and it works. Somebody had down-voted for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just assemble a regex for that.

- `0x` can be matched literally.
- `[[:xdigit:]]` is the [posix character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for matching hex digits.
- and it needs to be repeated `{6}` times

Lastly just add `/` delimiters for [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: Sorry, trying to understand this: So I would use it like `preg_replace('/[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}/', '', $str)`? Sorry im new to regex

Comment: If you're new to something, you'll only learn by trying it out, not from copy+pasteable snippets.